# Get google maps object of map in iframe

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I want to include a Google Maps powered application from an external page (www.marinetraffic.com) that already adds its own markers (Ships). I integrate this map using an iframe (this is the way recommended by the map provider).

However I want to be able to jump to certain markers (put on the map by marinetraffic.com). How do I get the corresponding Google Maps object with jQuery?

I see two problems here:

1. Get into the iframe DOM (using .content()? but how?)
2. Get the instance of the Google Maps object to add markers, jump to markers, zoom etc...

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Felix

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is from another domain then you'd get [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) exceptions, because that is considered cross site scripting and it is blocked by the browser.

Otherwise you can access the iframe and use selectors in the following way:

`$('#selector', frames['frame_name'].document).func_name();`

Comment: nice...so if I read the remote file through php and render it from my own domain i could go around the origin policy problem?

Comment: what do you mean by google maps objects? you wish to modify the map? I believe you should use the [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html). I haven't used javascript to modify already created maps, only to create ones from scratch. For this I've found [goMaps](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/index.php) to be the best jQuery library out there. I don't know if you can link it with your app though.

Comment: yes i mean the google maps object from the API...usually instanced like var map = new google.maps.Map(selector, options);

Comment: Sorry, I can not help you with the API, as mentioned before, I've only used the goMaps jQuery plugin to integrate google maps in websites. Hope somebody will help you out! :)